# What's probability of getting head on coin flip

Tags: probability

If I flip a coin for once, the chances I get the head as the result is $50\%$.

How can I calculate if I flip the coin for $2$ times, $10$ times or $100$ times, what is the chances I get head result for at least once?

I know this question is somehow stupid in this forum. But please show me how to calculate. Thanks.

Comment: A start: it's the probability that you get no heads  subtracted from $1$.

Comment: @DavidMitra Can you please explain better how the formula works? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done a lot easier: instead of calculating the probability of one head, two heads, three heads, ... one just needs to calculate the probability of no heads: that is simply $0.5^n$. If you subtract it from 1, you get the probability you want: it's because that's the chance of not no heads, meaning at least one head.
So, the formula is:
$1-0.5^n$

More formally:
if X is throwing at least one head,

$P(X)=1-P(\neg X)$, where $\neg X$ is throwing zero heads.

Answer (score 1):

The probability of getting *Head* at least once is equal to $1$ minus the probability of never getting *Head*, which is equal to $1$ minus the probability of getting *Tail* all the time.

And that's pretty easy to calculate...

Over $N$ coin-flips:

- The probability of getting only *Tail* is $(\frac{1}{2})^N$
- So the probability of getting at least one *Head* is $1-(\frac{1}{2})^N$

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be solved by bernoulli trial
Please see Wikipedia link.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_trial

Let n be the number of flips then for at least one head your answer should be = (nC1+nC2+nC3+...nCn)*(0.5^n) = 1-(0.5^n)